# How to get CherryPy version

Tags: python, ubuntu, terminal, cherrypy

I'm very new to CherryPy. I want to know which CherryPy version is installed in my machine. How to get CherryPy version in terminal?

Thank you for educate me.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
python -c "import cherrypy;print cherrypy.__version__"
```

Comment: It is interesting that this does not work on my raspy, though cherrypy is running. I get an "unknown" as result.

Comment: For python3 version `python3 -c "import cherrypy; print (cherrypy.__version__)"`

Answer (score 2):

**Python 3 syntax:**

```
python -c "import cherrypy;print(cherrypy.__version__)"
```

Answer (score 1):

In ubuntu, you just need to check the package version:

```
apt-cache policy python-cherrypy3
```

For example, in my system:

```
python-cherrypy3:
  Installed: 3.1.2-1
  Candidate: 3.1.2-1
  Version table:
 *** 3.1.2-1 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: doesn't this assume it was installed via apt or the package manager in general? maybe he installed it via pip etc?

Comment: @UkuLoskit Yes, I made that assumption. If that's not the case, then the answer from synthesizerpatel is the right one.

Answer (score 1):

is

```
dpkg -l | grep -i cherrypy
```

what you are looking for?